# MigLayout: reference component width by id

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I would like to layout my components as shown in this picture.

[image]

In short:

- aTextField must have a fixed size of 250px;
- bButton has a fixed size that dependes on the text label;
- bTextField should grow so that it's width plus bButton width reach
  250px.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutIdReference extends JFrame {

    private final MigLayout migLayout = new MigLayout("debug", "", "");
    private final JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Label A");
    private final JTextField aTextField = new JTextField();
    private final JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("Label B");
    private final JTextField bTextField = new JTextField();
    private final JButton bButton = new JButton("B Button");

    public MigLayoutIdReference() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(migLayout);
        add(aLabel, "");
        add(aTextField, "id aTextField, w 250!, wrap");
        add(bLabel, "");
        add(bTextField, "width aTextField.w-bButton.w");
        add(bButton, "id bButton, wrap");
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MigLayoutIdReference();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that MigLayout does not allow to calculate width based on other components that you recall by id.
When running my code I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size may not contain links
```

Am I missing something? Apart from referencing components by id, how could I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

- I changed the `MigLayout` constructor invocation and added row constraints and column constraints.
- I made `aTextField` span two columns.
- I gave `bTextField` the `growx` constraint.

Now the width of `bTextField` will adjust so that together with the width of `bButton` it will match the width of `aTextField`.

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutIdReference extends JFrame {
    private final MigLayout migLayout = new MigLayout("debug", "[][grow][]", "[][]");
    private final JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Label A");
    private final JTextField aTextField = new JTextField();
    private final JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("Label B");
    private final JTextField bTextField = new JTextField();
    private final JButton bButton = new JButton("B Button");

    public MigLayoutIdReference() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(migLayout);
        add(aLabel, "");
        add(aTextField, "id aTextField, w 250!, wrap, span 2");
        add(bLabel, "");
        add(bTextField, "growx");
        add(bButton, "id bButton,wrap");
        setResizable(true);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MigLayoutIdReference();
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Thanks, you made it. Anyway, do you know something about using components id to achieve this?